# How to search and replace these records with awk

Tags: perl, awk

I have following file:

```
     %0 Book
     %T Gale encyclopedia of medicine
     %A Deirdre S. Blanchfield
     %A Jacqueline L. Longe
     %A Gale Research Company
     %@ 0787654892
     %D 2002
     %I Gale Group 
     %R 10.1001/0787654892
     %F Gale_Thomson_Encyclopedias/Medicine and Health/0787654892/Gale Encyclopedia of Medicine. Vol. 1. 2nd ed.pdf

     %0 Book
     %T Encyclopedia of United States national security
     %A Richard J. Samuels
     %@ 0761929274
     %D 2006
     %I SAGE 
     %R 10.1001/0761929274
     %F Gale_Thomson_Encyclopedias/Politics, Law, Sociology/Encyclopedia of United States National Security_v1-2_0761929274 (Sage, 2006).pdf

     %0 Book
     %T Gale encyclopedia of medicine
     %A Deirdre S. Blanchfield
     %A Jacqueline L. Longe
     %A Gale Research Company
     %@ 0787654892
     %D 2002
     %I Gale Group 
     %R 10.1001/0787654892
     %F Gale_Thomson_Encyclopedias/Medicine and Health/0787654892/Gale Encyclopedia of Medicine. Vol. 2. 2nd ed.pdf
```

and would like to replace in the file with the filename in %F  following sequence.

```
    /ModDate(D:
```

with that

```
    /Subject (??? 2015, :. doi:<content of field %R>')/ModDate(D:
```

in the case from above (shown onyl the first record, but should be done for all records):

File with name:

```
     Gale_Thomson_Encyclopedias/Medicine and Health/0787654892/Gale Encyclopedia of Medicine. Vol. 1. 2nd ed.pdf
```

with follwing sequence:

```
      /ModDate(D:
```

replacing with

```
      /Subject (??? 2015, :. doi:10.1001/0787654892)/ModDate(D:
```

How can this be done with awk? Thanks a lot! a problem could be if the file has already a `/subject ( .. )` line in it. This should be deleted before the replacing is done.

ANy help is welcome.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there are a whole bunch of other files, which have a different format? Could you show us an example of one of them? It would also be good to explain specifically where you're stuck here, as it currently seems like you just want someone to do your work for you.

Comment: no alle records are in one file with this format. Each record start with `\r\n%0 Book`. and ther are only PDFs as file name. Well I will like to learn too, so I will make the work of course but I am not so familiar with awk, which is a great tool.The purpose is to define the DOI in the PDFs which are laoded in Endnote and the metadate are exported in Endnote Records format. If this could be done, then Endnote can import the PDFs automatically and link the PDF to the Endnote-Metadata.

Comment: _and would like to replace in the file with the filename in %F_ suggests that for each record in the file you have shown, there is a separate file elsewhere.

Comment: Yes TOM, in %F there is the location and filename of the PDF which should be processed. The Metadata of the PDF in the PDF is ASCII and can be searched and replaced.

Answer (score 0):

I tried following: and looks good:

```
     #!/usr/bin/perl

     use strict;
     use warnings;

     #my $mypdf = "";
     #my $mydoi = "";
     #my @rest;
     #my @rest2;
     my $pdfbuf;
     my $doibuf;

     while (<>) {
         chomp;

         #($mydoi, $mypdf)  = m/^%R (.*)|^%F (.+)/g;

         my  ( $mydoi, @rest) = m/^%R (.*)/g ;
            #print '->' . $mydoi if ($mydoi);
            $doibuf = $mydoi if ($mydoi);

         my  ( $mypdf, @rest2) = m/^%F (.*)/g ;
            #print '->' . $mypdf if ($mypdf);
            $pdfbuf = $mypdf if ($mypdf);


         #my ( $mydoi, @rest2 ) = m/^%R (.*)/g;


         if (($pdfbuf)&&($doibuf)) 
            {

               #print  "NOW: ",$doibuf,", and "   ;
               #print  $pdfbuf, "\n"  ;
               $doibuf =~ s/\//\\\//g;
               $pdfbuf =~ s/ //g;
               my $subj   =     '/Subject (??? 2015, :. doi:'.$doibuf.')' ;
               my $search =   '(/ModDate.D.*?\))';

               #my $cmd = 'awk -v add=\'' . $subj . '\' \'1; /' . $search . '/{print add}\'   ./' . $pdfbuf . ' >  ./' . $pdfbuf . '_withDOI' ;
               my $cmd = ' perl -pe \'s|' . $search . '|\1' . $subj . '|\'   ./' . $pdfbuf . ' >  ./' . $pdfbuf . '_withDOI' ;
               my $outputofshell = qx/$cmd/;

               print $cmd, "\n" ; 
               $doibuf=""; $pdfbuf="";


            }


     }
```